# msmq unhandled async exception in .net 4.5

Tags: c#, exception, async-await, .net-4.5, msmq

I've done some prototypes with MSMQ and faced weird behavior.

I have MSMQ service that sends data to some web service when there are messages incoming into queue. I'm turning off web service and expecting to see `System.ServiceModel.ServerTooBusyException` so that my messages would be returned to queue and will be sent later.
I'm hosting MSMQ service in console application.

Now, if I'm sending data to web service synchronously then I get expected behavior. If I send data asynchronously my console application crashes with unhandled exceptions `System.ServiceModel.ServerTooBusyException`.

Here is pseudo code:

**Console**

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomainOnUnhandledException;

using (MSMQServiceHost serviceHost = new MSMQServiceHost(typeof(Service1)))
{
    serviceHost.Open();

     Console.WriteLine("Press any key to stop service...");
     Console.ReadKey(true);
}

private static void CurrentDomainOnUnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs unhandledExceptionEventArgs)
{
   MSMQ.Utils.LoggerHelper.GetLogger().ErrorFormat("CurrentDomainOnUnhandledException. {0}", unhandledExceptionEventArgs);
}
```

**Service**

```
[OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired = true)]
public async  void GetData(int start, int end)
{
    try
    {
      using (WebServiceReference.Service1Client webClient = new WebServiceReference.Service1Client())
      {
        string data = await webClient.GetDataAsync(start);
        //string data = webClient.GetData(start);
        MSMQ.Utils.LoggerHelper.GetLogger().InfoFormat("Received info from web service. Data\t{0}", data);
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    MSMQ.Utils.LoggerHelper.GetLogger().ErrorFormat("{1}\r\n{0}", e.Message, e.GetType().FullName);
    throw;
}
```

}

In case of synchronous call I get big list of logged errors, but application is not crashed. In case of asynchronous call I get the same list of logged errors plus the same number of CurrentDomainOnUnhandledException's (System.ServiceModel.ServerTooBusyException)

> > mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.ThrowAsync.AnonymousMethod__5(object state) Unknown
> >         mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)   Unknown
> >         mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)   Unknown
> >         mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()  Unknown
> >         mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()    Unknown

My awaitable is observable - I've subscribed to TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException and nothing there.
How to properly use async in that case, so that I get all the benefits from APM and my application wouldn't crash?

Answer (score 2):

I got it.

The problem is with `async` modifier in my service operation. Correct version:

```
[OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired = true)]
public async Task GetData(int start, int end)
{
    try
    {
        await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            using (WebServiceReference.Service1Client webClient = new WebServiceReference.Service1Client())
            {
                 Task<string> data = GetWebClientData(start, webClient);
                 MSMQ.Utils.LoggerHelper.GetLogger().InfoFormat("Received info from web service. Data\t{0}", data.Result);
            }
        }
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
      MSMQ.Utils.LoggerHelper.GetLogger().ErrorFormat("{1}\r\n{0}", e.Message, e.GetType().FullName);
     throw;
  }
}

private static async Task<string> GetWebClientData(int start, WebServiceReference.Service1Client webClient)
{
    return await webClient.GetDataAsync(start);
}
```